# Given a smooth map $g: M\to R^+$, show that there is a smooth function $f:M → R^+$ such that $f(x) < g(x)$ for all $x ∈ M$.

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I'm trying to prove the following proposition.

> Let M be a smooth manifold and let $g:M→R^+$ be a continuous
>   function. Show that there is a smooth function $f:M→ R^+$ such that
>   $f(x) < g(x)$ for all $x ∈ M$. (Hint: Use partition of unity on an
>   open cover of M by coordinate balls.)

I've only come up with $f(x) := g(x)/2 $.However, considering the given hint, I'm guessing that does not work, and I don't know why.

**Edit:**

As it is pointed out, since $g$ is not smooth, $f$ does not have to be as well, so the question is now, how to find $f$.

Comment: your $f$ need not be smooth

Comment: $M$ is smooth, but $g$ might not be.

Comment: @XIAODAQU Yes, you are right, but how to find $f$ now ?

Comment: Do it for a small co-ordinate chart with compact closure at first. Then use a partition of unity to glue them together.

Comment: @IgnorantMathematician If I could do that, hint clearly says how to extend that to the whole manifold already; but the problem is, how to construct $f$ for a neighbourhood of $x$.

Comment: You're looking for a good way to cook up smooth approximations to $g$. Are you familiar with the Stone-Wierstrass theorem?

Comment: @TimTheEnchanter Nope.

Comment: You might find this page usefull [1]. I doubt you can make much progress with this kind of problem without some tools from analysis so you might as well give it a look.

[1] -https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the issue is now constructing such an $f$ on a neighbourhood of a point $x$. Consider a fundamental neighborhood $U_0$ around $x$ and restrict the local diffeomorphism $\phi$ to an open $U$ containing $x$ such that $\bar U \subset U_0$ and is compact. Now with the local coordinate system $(x_1,x_2\dots x_n)$ induced by $\phi$ consider the subalgebra of $C(\bar U,\mathbb R)$ generated by polynomials. It contains the constant functions and separates points. Thus, by Stone-Weierstrass we can approximate $g$ uniformly by such polynomials, which are in fact smooth.

Now as $\bar U$ is compact, $g$ has a minimum, say $m>0$. We can find $f\in C(\bar U,\mathbb R)$ such that $|f-g|<m/2$ on $\bar U$. Then we have that $f$ maps into $\mathbb R^+$ and furthermore $f/2 < g/2 + m/2 \le g$. Thus we have constructed the desired $f$ on $\bar U$. The rest follows by using a partition of unity.

Comment: Looks like an overkill.

Comment: It was the first thing I thought of so may very well be so. Do you know a more elementary/slick way to do it? @IgnorantMathematician